# Adding a pagebreak by indesign scripting

Tags: scripting, flash-cs5, adobe-indesign, page-break

I have a routine which reads an XML file and builds an ID document. How do I create a page break by adding to the current insertionPoint? I tried it with

```
story.insertionPoints.lastItem().contents += SpecialCharacters.pageBreak;
```

but those special characters seem to apply only to XML. What is the alternative? - I'm using ID CS5.

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer elsewhere. The trick is to use the assignment instead of the concatenation operator:

```
story.insertionPoints.lastItem().contents = SpecialCharacters.pageBreak;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the InDesign JS API documentation, it's actually:

```
story.insertionPoints.lastItem().contents = SpecialCharacters.PAGE_BREAK;
```